# Eclipse Package Explorer Oddity

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

Recently whenever I open my workspace in Eclipse the Package Explorer has always defaulted to focusing on a single folder of all my projects/resource files. I've put up with this for a few months since I can just "Up to" to get back to the project level.

However, I'd like to get this sorted. Does anyone have any idea how I can stop Eclipse opening this specific folder as its default?

Comment: What's the name of this folder?  Could you have it in a working set mode?

Comment: It always opens in the "res/values" folder of my Android project

Answer (score 6):

You've probably already found the solution by now, but I recently ran into the same problem and found a solution that seemed to work for me and thought I'd share.

Close Eclipse and open your workspace's workbench.xml file for edit:

```
gedit <yourEclipseWorkspaceDir>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml
```

Search the doc for the name of the folder your Package Explorer keeps defaulting to. This should be the value of the path attribute in a line like this:

```
<input factoryID="org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory" path="<theOffendingFolder>" type="2"/>
```

Change the value of the path attribute to point to the desired folder, or delete that input line entirely if you want the Package Explorer to show you the default project level. Save the file and open Eclipse.

Comment: same issue, no workbench.xml in place, package explorer not linked to editor??? I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: Works great, I finally located the file workbench.xml on my Mac machine: .metadata->.plugins->org.eclipse.ui.workbench->workbench.xml (tag/section "navigationHistory" -> remove "input" line)

Comment: Worked for me.  I'm concerned that I don't know the root cause of the problem.  For now, I'll just chalk it up to an Eclipse bug.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related to the files automatically opened when you start your workspace (because it was closed in that state) and the package explorer "Link with editor button". This button at the top right of package explorer view allows to synchronize the current visible file in the editor with the package explorer (personally I often use this feature but I know some of my colleagues hate it ;-)).

Hope this can help
Manu

Comment: Don't have that button enabled (don't like it). I'm always running with the Package Explorer in the outer most node. Don't think its saving this from the closing state