# Eclipse always starting within a particular project

Tags: eclipse

This might be a stupid question, but although I have a few projects now on my Eclipse workspace, everytime I start the program it starts within a project folder in package explorer, and with that project name on the title, even if I am working on different projects and that particular one has not been touched for a long time.

It's like that project in particular has somehow been marked as "main" and I don't know how to reverse it back to a default state. Not that this is a serious issue or anything, it just bugs me.

My eclipse.ini:

```
double -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? With which perspective/plugin do you experience this issue (Java, CDT, etc.)?

Comment: Eclipse 3.7.2 ("Eclipse for Android"), Java perspective.

Comment: That's strange, never experienced that. What is your working set is set to (press the small triangle in the package explorer's upper left corner). Is it *Window working set*?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was thinking perhaps it's something related to Mylyn?

Comment: How do you start Eclipse? What is in your eclipse.ini?

Comment: I start Eclipse by double clicking on the .exe. I edited the original post showing my eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding always starting with a specific project, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8598667/1599890. It seems to have helped a few people.

Regarding the title, open `Preferences -> General -> Workspace` and check the `Workspace name (shown in window title)`setting there.